# momentjs: how to get the date in a specific timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

In a nutshell I want moment to respect server's timezone. I've set my machine's timezone to Alaska but I'm passing a Brisbane timezone string to moment. Now I need `moment.toDate` to return a date instance in the same timezone as the one I pass in the moment constructor; e.g.

```
m = moment("2016-11-20T08:00:00+10:00")
m.format() // "2016-11-20T08:00:00+10:00" 
m.toDate() // Sat Nov 19 2016 13:00:00 GMT-0900 (AKST)
```

I want to get a `Date` instance from moment that's in the input timezone; e.g. somehow get `toDate` to return `Sun Nov 20 2016 08:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)`.

FWIW I have tried the same code with and without `moment.tz.setDefault` and while it correctly changes the `format` result, `toDate` always uses the machine's timezone!

*Update*

The reason I need this behaviour is that some JavaScript libraries and controls don't understand `moment` and only work with `Date` and the time/date gets skewed when presented back by them. One example, the one I'm currently dealing with, is jQuery UI date picker control. I want the date picker to show the current date as it's on the server (or on a specific timezone).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The `Date` object represents the time in UTC internally, and can *only* use the time zone of the machine its running on when projected.

There's absolutely no way to produce a `Date` object that uses an arbitrary time zone.  Any examples you may come across that try to manipulate the `Date` object (such by adding or subtracting time zone offsets) are fundamentally flawed.

Moment itself has great time zone support, including the moment-timezone extension for working with named time zones instead of just time zone offsets.  But once you go back to a `Date` object - you're back at the mercy of the behavior of that object.

Sorry, but there's no way to achieve what you are asking.  Perhaps you could elaborate as to *why* you wanted to do this, and I could recommend a workaround.

---

Update:  With regards to *your* update, usually there is a mechanism for getting the value from a date picker as *text*, rather than as a date object.  With the example of the jQuery UI date picker control, the `onSelect` event gives it to you as text already, or you can simply call `.val()` instead of `.datepicker('getDate')` to get the text out of the field.  Once you have a textual value, you can then parse it with moment however you like.

Similarly, when setting the value, you don't necessarily need a `Date` object.  You could just set the value of the textbox as a string, or you can pass a string to the [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) function.

In most cases, you won't have to go through a `Date` object.  But if for some reason you do, then you'll need to artificially construct one with something crazy like:

```
var d = new Date(m.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
```

Normally, I'd be against that - but if it's just there to get the pass a value to a UI control, then it's probably ok.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the real reason to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a moment in the same timezone as the moment string, but toDate is always in the local timezone.

```
d = "2016-11-20T08:00:00+10:00"
m = moment(d).utcOffset(d)
m.format()
m.toDate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Chales. I don't have any problems with `format` - I need a `Date` instance in the original timezone.