# Why moment-timezone does not apply given timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, datetime-conversion

I check moment in the Chrome Developer Tools on the moment-timezone website: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

I execute:

```
moment(new Date(2011, 9, 16, 12)).tz('America/Los_Angeles').toDate()
```

and the result is still:

> Sun Oct 16 2011 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)

Why moment-timezone didn't apply given timezone and I get `Central European Daylight Time`?

Comment: Just a thought... You are using moment.js so you don't need to deal with `Date` oddities. If you feed it with `new Date(2011, 9, 16, 12)` you're defeating the overall purpose.

Comment: Have you added time zone list to moment.tz object?

Comment: @AnkitSolanki I didn't, they did, I am no the author of https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: if you have import moment js file without timezone then you have to add all time zone then this can works.

Comment: This is *close* to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618728/momentjs-how-to-get-the-date-in-a-specific-timezone), though not exact duplicate so I'll keep this one open.  Still, you should read.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you create `new Date(2011, 9, 16, 12)`, it gets **October 16<sup>th</sup> 2011 at 12:00** in whatever the browser's timezone is. Then `tz` converts this to the specified timezone, and `toDate()` converts back to the date object (using the browser's timezone).

If you want to create **October 16<sup>th</sup> 2011 at 12:00** in Los Angeles timezone, there's no need to use `new Date`. You can use `moment.tz` directly:

```
moment.tz('2011-10-16 12:00', 'America/Los_Angeles')
```

The output will be:

> Sun Oct 16 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0700

You can also create the date passing values instead of a string ([check the docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) to see all options):

```
moment.tz([2011, 9, 16, 12], 'America/Los_Angeles')
moment.tz({ year: 2011, month: 9, day: 16, hour: 12 }, 'America/Los_Angeles')
```

All the above produce the same date (**October 16<sup>th</sup> 2011 at 12:00** in Los Angeles timezone).

Note that the values are zero-indexed (January is zero), while in the string, months are 1-indexed (January is `1`).

---

Calling `toDate()` on the above will convert the date/time to your browser's default timezone as well.

Comment: Keep in mind this creates a `moment` object.  From there, one should still use a function like `format` to get the desired output.

Comment: @MattJohnson Indeed! But as the OP didn't specify that they want the date in a specific format, I didn't include that in the question. But thanks for reminding!